# python regex invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am testing a code from a current 2600 magazine for a wordlist generator based off a bunch of searches in google. I get an invalid syntax from this line:

```
    results.extend(re.findall("<a href="/%201D([^/%201D]*)/%201D">class=(?:1|s)",data.read()))
```

I am new to regex so I did some research on the basics of re and it seemed fairly easy but I still didn't understand the /%201D. I did a search on it and found thats it's a hex of a char code. I am still stuck on making this work. [Here](http://pastebin.com/gknjzDsj) is the rest of the code. The line I'm having a problem with is line 36.

This is the function:

```
import re, sys, os, urllib
### custom useragent   ###
class AppURLopener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0(compatable;MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"

urllib._urlopener = AppURLopener()
uopen   = urllib.urlopen
uencode = urllib.urlencode

def google(query, numget=10, verbose=0):     
    numget = int(numget)
    start = 0
    results = []

    if verbose == 2:
            print("[+]Getting " + str(numget) + " results")

            while len(results) < numget:
                    print("[+]" + str(len(results)) + " so far...")
                    data = uopen("https://www.google.com/search?q="+query+"&star="+str(start))

                    if data.code != 200:
                            print("Error " + str(data.code))
                            break

                    results.extend(re.findall("<a href="/%201D([^/%201D]*)/%201D">class=(?:1|s)",data.read()))
                    print(data.read())
                    start += 10

                    if verbose == 2:
                            print("[+] Got " + str(numget) + " results")

                    return results[:numget]
```

Comment: Move the essential parts of code here, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to escape the " in `<a href="`

```
"<a href=\"/%201D([^/%201D]*)/%201D\">class=(?:1|s)"
```

second, `%20` encodes a single space in URLs, so `%201D` corresponds to `" 1D"`.